# How does a country's military decide where to place draftees?

Tags: war, conscription

Something I've wondered about for some time is where countries that have a military draft place draftees. For example, in WW II, when many countries were at war and many had drafts after the volunteers were no longer sufficient, to which branch of their various services did they send new draftees? Were people with experience of the sea, like fishermen and crew of freighters, typically placed in the Navy while farmers were typically placed in the Army? Aside from experienced pilots, what sort of civilians were wanted for the Air Force?

I'm assuming that volunteers typically volunteered for a specific service and were placed there if a need could be found for them; if no need existed, they might be sent where the need was greatest. Even draftees might be able to express a preference in some countries but I suspect they couldn't be sure of getting their choice.

I'm trying to understand what the military did with new people if they didn't have a civilian skill that made a tentative placement obvious, like someone with a pilot's license? Would your average farmer or shoe salesmen simply go to whatever service was in the most dire need of bodies or was there more to it?

I realize that every service had health and fitness requirements that had to met. They must also have had times when they really didn't need any more people in whatever job the draftee wanted to do so would shunt that person to something else. And of course many people must have proved inadequate during training so that they couldn't have their first choice. I'm just looking to understand the process that was used to choose where a given person went to serve their country.

I'm sure these procedures varied from country to country, from war to war, and depending on the stage of the war but the general outlines for ANY war and country should be interesting.

Comment: I don't think there is a universal answer to this. Certainly military history is so rife with stupendous incompetence that for any reasonable system there must be examples of countries that did something else.

Comment: I'm skeptical. I suspect that the answers are particular, rather than general, and will be found in the military policy of each individual country.  [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: [Highly sophisticated processes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=657nmpZAYr8)

Comment: Where do you think do they place volunteers? And why would there be a difference?

Comment: This is equivalent in broadness to a "how did Ancient Rome do X?" question.

Answer (score 2):

**"It is complicated."**

First, the draft did not just exist if the number of volunteers was insufficient. In peacetime, the purpose of the draft could be to *train future reservists.* That means draftees go through little more than training before they are sent home -- except for the occasional reserve training recall.

But the more relevant part of the answer is **the needs of the service.**

- Clerks look at the draftees and classify them according to physical and mental exams, education and service records, and similar factors. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_Training_and_Service_Act_of_1940) is the list of US classifications of WWII draftees, [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tauglichkeitsgrad) is the recent German one.
- The military administration **decides** how many draftees they need in each service, and how they should be qualified. In a way, they are "fighting over" the pool of available recruits. Each service will get a few draftees with *high potential* (healthy, intelligent, educated) and a few with *low potential* (not healthy, not intelligent, not educated). The Air Force needs pilots and mechanics, but also someone to peel potatoes. Often the infantry got more below-average troops.
- Draftees *may* also be allowed to make a request.

Then the clerks try to fill the wishes of the administration with as little fuss as possible. If they can, they will match wishes, qualifications, and open slots. But most important, draftees go where they are **needed by the service**.